# Changing the image size to fit header box

Tags: css

How do I resize my image to only fit the header for my website? My background-image is url("image/header\header.jpg"); 
Background-size: cover; Need assistance thanks. The picture isnt my work but a tutorial I'm working with. [image]

Comment: You need to provide Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example not a picture in order to help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use **thumbnail class** in **bootstrap** for this purpose.

For more info on this check out Bootstrap CDN.

Comment: So I tried using using bootstraps cdn <link="stylesheet provided by "getbootstrap.com" and no results.  I wrapped my header in a class and want my img to cover it's background. Only the header and not spread out all over the page.

Comment: I fixed it thanks for the assistance. My header was the parent of too many elements haha.